# C++ Nested Iterators for Sets

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, set

I am trying use nested iterators for sets as shown below but gives an err:

error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator’ and ‘int’)
for(auto itj = iti+1; itj != st.end(); itj++){

```
int alternate(string s) {
    set<char> st;
    for(char x : s){
        st.insert(x);
    }

    for(auto iti = st.begin(); iti != st.end(); iti++){
        //string t = "";
        for(auto itj = iti+1; itj != st.end(); itj++){
            cout<<*iti<<" "<<*itj<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code alone should not cause that error. But I assume there are parts missing? what is `s` for example? If `auto iti = 0` is the code, `auto itj = iti+1` should not cause any problems (iti and itj are deduced to `int`).

Comment: Your code says that `iti` is an integer, but the message say that it is an iterator. Are you sure that you posted the code you're compiling?

Comment: What are `st`, `s` and `t`? You don't seem to use `test` here, why declare it?

Comment: The previous code was part of a bigger problem. I've reformatted the code for better understanding. I hope you guys understand it now? @MikaelH

Comment: The previous code was part of a bigger problem. I've reformatted the code for better understanding. I hope you guys understand it now? @molbdnilo

Comment: The previous code was part of a bigger problem. I've reformatted the code for better understanding. I hope you guys understand it now? @Caleth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set`'s iterator does not satisfy the named requirement [`LegacyRandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). It only satisfies [`LegacyBidirectionalIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator).

So `iti + 1` is not a valid expression, there's no matching operator+ for the iterator.

To fix your problem, you can use `std::next`.

```
for (auto iti = st.begin(); iti != st.end(); ++iti){
    for (auto itj = std::next(iti); itj != st.end(); ++itj){
        cout << *iti << " " << *itj << endl;
    }
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GSRLYC).

Comment: `std::next()` and `++iti` modifies the iterator. `iti+1` would not change `iti`.

Comment: @MikaelH `std::next` doesn't modify it's parameter, you may be thinking of `std::advance`

Comment: @Caleth, that's true, thanks.